# What is the meaning, form and pronunciation for the items listed in bold?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, language-formation, meaning

> Tide laundry detergent is meant to be used for household cleaning purposes, but thieves are turning it into something dirty. Authorities are reporting **a spike in** thefts of Tide, and in some cities they are setting up task forces where the detergent is sold to track the number of bottles in stores. Police believe thieves are using the soap on the black market, which retails for $10-$20, to buy drugs. On the black market, Tide is often referred to as "liquid gold" and can go for $5-$10 per bottle.
>   Last year, in St. Paul, Minnesota, a man is alleged to have stolen $25,000 worth of Tide over 15 months before **he was captured by authorities**. Stores such as CVS have amped up security measures to prevent theft; at some locations the detergent is kept in a locked container and an employee must retrieve it for customers.
>   So why is Tide the only detergent being targeted? Authorities have **come up with** several reasons: **It might be** because Tide is instantly recognizable because of its Day-Glo orange bottle; or it may be because it is one of the most expensive brands of laundry detergent or because it does not have serial numbers, so it cannot be tracked.
>   On social media, people are calling the theft trend "bizarre" and many are blaming it on the tough economy and rising gas prices. One person tweeted that the thefts could “stem from inflation”. 
>   A spokesperson for Procter & Gamble, the manufacturer of Tide, called the thefts "unfortunate”.

I am trying to help my son.

1. I know *he was captured by authorities* is a past tense, passive voice, *by authorities* (because it's important who caused the action not who did it). But how would I write the form?
2. *A spike in*, is it an increase? A noun? Do you normally say this?
3. *It might be*, subject and verb?
4. *Come up with*, as in listed?

English is not our native language and I want to help him with his homework, but I don`t understand it myself.

Comment: Homework questions are generally not appropriate for this website, unless they are about a clearly described, coherent, and linguistically suitable subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Especially *form* is indeed a vague question. But I'll try to give you answers that may pacify his teacher.

1. *He was captured by authorities*. Form: past tense, passive voice sounds good.
2. *A spike in*. Meaning: a sudden increase in x. It is a fairly common expression. Form: unclear. It is a noun group, so I would say "noun".
3. *It might be.* Form: simple past tense plus infinitive. It doesn't make much sense to describe the form of "it". "Subject" is not about form but about syntax.
4. *Come up with.* Meaning: have thought of several reasons / have suggested several reasons. Form: infinitive.